# Firefox doesn't load CSS file

Tags: css, firefox, github

My firefox Browser doesn't load the CSS file of GitHub.
i have searched and found that it's related to the php.ini file **but** i couldn't solve it.
[screenshot of how i see gihub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx7Io.png)

Comment: Do you have the source code to show ?

Comment: @Selvam 
Source code of what?

Comment: have you tried to get url of css and open that in new tab?

Comment: @MuhammadMagdi your page structure ( HTML, CSS ... )

Comment: I do not think it is related to the php.ini file as PHP is not related in any way to Firefox XD Clear your cache and reload the page.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, because you do not have a programming-related question, but a problem with a specific site or program from the end-user perspective.

Comment: @Raimonds
the URL of the CSS file does't open.

Comment: @Blackbam
didn't work.

Comment: @MuhammadMagdi Do you have a Plugin installed in Firefox which may cause the problem? Any custom settings? Is there an error in your debugger console (F12) ? Which one?

Comment: @Blackbam
The debugger console says:
"Style sheet couldn't be loaded" + its path

Comment: @Muhammad Magdi Did you try if you can load the stylesheet by path for its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that Github DNS are under DDOS attack.

Add this to your /etc/host file (or c:\windows\system32\driver\etc\host for window) :

`192.30.253.113 github.com
151.101.60.133 assets-cdn.github.com`